# MySql group by with having clause

Tags: mysql, group-by, having, sql-query-store

I have a table message with following structure

```
id   -  to_number     -  from_number  -  message       - send_to_podio_time
100  -  +16235708320  - +16232992010  -  test message1 - 2019-03-07 18:31:12
101  -  +16232992010  - +16235708320  -  test message2 - 2019-03-07 18:31:15
102  -  +16235708786  - +16232992010  -  test message3 - 2019-03-07 18:31:16
103  -  +16232992010  - +16235708786  -  test message4 - 2019-03-07 18:31:18
```

I need to get the count of conversation thread between two phone numbers
The expected output is

```
phone_numbers              -  count
+16235708320:+16232992010  -   1
+16235708786:+16232992010  -   1
```

Can anybody help me with the appropriate query ?

Comment: but message1  and message2 are both between same numbers. similar for message 3 and 4 so shouldn't expected result show "2" in both rows?

Comment: @Sachem message1 and message2 are b/w same numbers(one message thread). Like that message3 and message4 are b/w another same numbers(one message thread). So count should be 1

Comment: I don't quite get this. How is this "1 message thread" if +16235708320 replied with "message2" ? :)

Comment: Its a conversation. Conversation between same phone numbers. I want to get each conversation separately. That is what i needed. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(':', from_number, to_number), COUNT(*) 
FROM table_name
GROUP BY from_number, to_number;
```

This will show 4 rows as the result though, because reversed "order" between messages 1 and 2 (and similarly 3 and 4) will be treated separately.
But since you wanted "1" as the result in each row, perhaps this is what you were looking for?

Comment: first 2 rows are same thread. So it should be counted as 1. Like that the next 2 rows

Comment: how do you know it's the same thread, not having a thread_id column in the table?

Comment: to achieve what you want, you should query for "from" and "to" numbers separately (not concatenated) and then you can easily filter out "duplicates" in a loop. just check if a pair or reversed pair is not already in the final array, and if it is then don't add it to it.